# Pandas computer hourly average and set at middle of interval

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to compute the hourly mean for a time series of wind speed and direction, but I want to set the time at the half hour. So, the average for values from 14:00 to 15:00 will be at 14:30. Right now, I can only seem to get it on left or right of the interval. Here is what I currently have:

```
ts_g=[item.replace(second=0, microsecond=0) for item in dates_g]
dg = {'ws': data_g.ws, 'wdir': data_g.wdir}
df_g = pandas.DataFrame(data=dg, index=ts_g, columns=['ws','wdir'])
grouped_g = df_g.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('H'))
hourly_ws_g = grouped_g['ws'].mean()
hourly_wdir_g = grouped_g['wdir'].mean()
```

the output for this looks like:

```
2016-04-08 06:00:00+00:00     46.980000
2016-04-08 07:00:00+00:00     64.313333
2016-04-08 08:00:00+00:00     75.678333
2016-04-08 09:00:00+00:00    127.383333
2016-04-08 10:00:00+00:00    145.950000
2016-04-08 11:00:00+00:00    184.166667
....
```

but I would like it to be like:

```
2016-04-08 06:30:00+00:00     54.556
2016-04-08 07:30:00+00:00     78.001
....
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

So the easiest way is to resample and then use linear interpolation:

```
In [21]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')

In [22]: ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
    ...: 

In [23]: ts.head()
Out[23]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    0.796704
2011-01-01 01:00:00   -1.153179
2011-01-01 02:00:00   -1.919475
2011-01-01 03:00:00    0.082413
2011-01-01 04:00:00   -0.397434
Freq: H, dtype: float64

In [24]: ts2 = ts.resample('30T').interpolate()

In [25]: ts2.head()
Out[25]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    0.796704
2011-01-01 00:30:00   -0.178237
2011-01-01 01:00:00   -1.153179
2011-01-01 01:30:00   -1.536327
2011-01-01 02:00:00   -1.919475
Freq: 30T, dtype: float64

In [26]:
```

I believe this is what you need.

### Edit to add clarifying example

Perhaps it's easier to see what's going on without random Data:

```
In [29]: ts.head()
Out[29]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    0
2011-01-01 01:00:00    1
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2
2011-01-01 03:00:00    3
2011-01-01 04:00:00    4
Freq: H, dtype: int64

In [30]: ts2 = ts.resample('30T').interpolate()

In [31]: ts2.head()
Out[31]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2011-01-01 00:30:00    0.5
2011-01-01 01:00:00    1.0
2011-01-01 01:30:00    1.5
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2.0
Freq: 30T, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is already several years old and uses the API that has long been deprecated. Modern Pandas already provides the `resample` method that is easier to use than `pandas.TimeGrouper`. Yet it allows only *left* and *right* labelled intervals but getting the intervals centered at the middle of the interval is not readily available.

Yet this is not hard to do.

First we fill in the data that we want to resample:

```
ts_g=[datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2019-11-20') + 
      datetime.timedelta(minutes=10*x) for x in range(0,100)]
dg = {'ws': range(0,100), 'wdir': range(0,100)}

df_g = pd.DataFrame(data=dg, index=ts_g, columns=['ws','wdir'])
df_g.head()
```

The output would be:

```
                       ws   wdir
2019-11-20 00:00:00     0   0
2019-11-20 00:10:00     1   1
2019-11-20 00:20:00     2   2
2019-11-20 00:30:00     3   3
2019-11-20 00:40:00     4   4
```

Now we first resample to 30 minute intervals

```
grouped_g = df_g.resample('30min')
halfhourly_ws_g = grouped_g['ws'].mean()
halfhourly_ws_g.head()
```

The output would be:

```
2019-11-20 00:00:00     1
2019-11-20 00:30:00     4
2019-11-20 01:00:00     7
2019-11-20 01:30:00    10
2019-11-20 02:00:00    13
Freq: 30T, Name: ws, dtype: int64
```

Finally the trick to get the centered intervals:

```
hourly_ws_g = halfhourly_ws_g.add(halfhourly_ws_g.shift(1)).div(2)\
                             .loc[halfhourly_ws_g.index.minute % 60 == 30]
hourly_ws_g.head()
```

This would produce the expected output:

```
2019-11-20 00:30:00     2.5
2019-11-20 01:30:00     8.5
2019-11-20 02:30:00    14.5
2019-11-20 03:30:00    20.5
2019-11-20 04:30:00    26.5
Freq: 60T, Name: ws, dtype: float64
```