# pandas -- label a DatetimeIndex by interval center?

Tags: pandas, datetime

Is there is a way to label a pandas DatetimeIndex by its center value, e.g. the middle of the month for a monthly interval? For me, this would be much more intuitive than the default labels at the beginning or end of the interval.

Unfortunately, my understanding from the pandas documentation is that the only default label values are 'left' and 'right'.

This question does provide a way to calculate the middle of an interval:
[Pandas computer hourly average and set at middle of interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431595/pandas-computer-hourly-average-and-set-at-middle-of-interval/58994745#58994745)
However, I am wondering if there might be more direct approach available.